# Hades,Hibernate and JUnit: Persistence not happening after transaction

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, junit, persistence

I have a JUnit test that needs to update a column of an existing row before further operations are performed and validated based on that column. But my problem is that column is not getting updated even after leaving the @Transactional boundary. My code looks kind of like below.

```
@RunWith(UnitilsJUnit4TestClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationContext(
{ "applicationContext.xml" })
public class TestClass
{
   @SpringBeanByType
   TestTableDBUtil util;

   @Test
   public void test()
   {
      util.updateColumnA(id, true);
      /* I do not see the column A value commited on returning from this function */
      /* Operations and validations based on the updated column ensue */
   }
}

@Component
@ContextConfiguration(locations =
{ "/applicationContext.xml" })
@TransactionConfiguration
public TestTableDBUtil
{
    @Autowired
    private MyTableRepository myTableRepo;

    @Transactional(readOnly = false, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
    public void updateColumnA(Long id, boolean value)
    {
       MyEntity myEntity = myTableRepo.readByPrimaryKey(id);
       myEntity.setColumnA(value);
       myTableRepo.saveAndFlush(myEntity);   
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you doing a merge in the saveAndFlush() method of MyTableRepository?

Comment: I decided to use Unitils transactions and have auto commit set to true in my tests. Was never able to make my tests work with SpringJUnit4TestClassRunner.

Comment: How about a look at your bean configuration files?